# Unable to mask a text field

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, maskedinput

I am trying to mask a text field that is created after an `Ajax` response. Everyhing is okay with `Ajax` request and response. To make this i am using
jquery `maskedinput` plugin. I have already imported neccesarry js files to my `HTML` page. Currently i am unable to do this. I think `Ajax` loading causes that but i dont know how to fix this problem. Any help will be appriciated. Here is what i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#stuPhoneText").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

Comment: @Donal as i said above i have included all neccesary js files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone mask with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery)

Comment: @user3659034 i dont understand what you mean ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946500/order-of-events-for-dynamically-added-elements-and-masked-input-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to run

```
$("#stuPhoneText").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

on the 'complete' callback of your ajax function.  Not in the document ready.

I'm sure the plugin isn't written in such a way that it constantly examines the entire Dom for new elements matching the ID you specified.

Something like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: "targetURL.html",
   type: "POST",
   complete: function(){ $("#stuPhoneText").mask("(999) 999-9999"); },
   dataType: "html"
});
```